# getting error "string index out of range" after a few cycle in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and using python 3.7 version. I am trying to add some words in a list and convert them in the numeric form but, I am getting error.  
Here is the code:

```
for file in files:
        f = open(direct+file, encoding='utf8')
        lines = f.read().split("\n")

        for line in lines:
            data = []
            words = line.split(' ')

            for element in dictionary:
                data.append(words.count(element[0]))

            feature_set.append(data)
```

When I run this code it's getting    `IndexError: string index out of range` error in this `data.append(words.count(element[0]))` line. I don't understand what should I do now.

Comment: What is `dictionary`? You don't show us what it is, but it looks like one of its elements is an empty string.

Comment: dictionary = [{"some":75,"text",8,"here",2}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite unclear but, still I will give it a try.

I will try to show you the possible scenario where this error could come.
basically you are trying to index an empty string. So your `element` is having an empty string at some place.
following will reproduce the issue:

`dictionary = ['abc','']
 for element in dictionary:
        element[0]`

So as per above example. You are hitting the scenario on second iteration.
Add `len(element)>0` check before indexing `element` for avoiding this issue.

Comment: thank you so much. actually, I have some empty string in the dictionary. after deleting those items the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong with how you have the dictionary initialized.
if you are looking for a python dictionary, it should be set as:

dictionary = {"some":75,"text":8,"here":2}

```
then you can run the below code:
```

for element in dictionary:

```
"here you will get the keys in the dictionary and you can do the word count as you are doing above"
```